# Can a powershell module call functions in its importer's scope?

Tags: powershell, module

Is it possible for a powershell module to call functions that live in its importer's scope?

For example, say I have module.psm1, and script.ps1. Inside script.ps1 I import module.psm1, and define a function called Execute-Payload. Is there any way for the code in module.psm1 to call Execute-Payload?

Comment: You want to load a function saved on one script into your main script?

Comment: Yes, but ideally I'd like to do that without creating namespace pollution.

Answer (score 1):

From inside an (advanced) function in your module, you can use [`$PSCmdlet.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.invokescript#System_Management_Automation_CommandInvocationIntrinsics_InvokeScript_System_Management_Automation_SessionState_System_Management_Automation_ScriptBlock_System_Object___) with argument `$PSCmdlet.SessionState` and a script block created *from a string* to execute arbitrary code in the caller's scope.

<sup>The technique was gratefully adapted from [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7944#issuecomment-427468659).</sup>

For brevity, the following code demonstrates the technique with a *dynamic* module created with [`New-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module), but it equally applies to regular, persisted modules:

```sh
# The function to call from the module.
function Execute-Payload {
  "Inside Execute-Payload in the script's scope."
}

# Create (and implicitly import) a dynamic module.
$null = New-Module {

  # Define the advanced module function that calls `Execute-Payload`
  # in its caller's scope.
  function Invoke-Something {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    $PSCmdlet.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(
      $PSCmdlet.SessionState,
      # Pass a *string* with arbitrary code to execute in the caller's scope to 
      # [scriptblock]::Create().
      # !! It is imperative that [scriptblock]::Create() be used, with
      # !! a *string*, as it creates an *unbound* script block that then 
      # !! runs in the specified session. 
      # !! If needed, use string expansion to "bake" module-local variable 
      # !! values into the string, or pass parameters as additional arguments.
      # !! However, if a script block is passed *by the caller*,
      # !! bound to *its* context, it *can* be used as-is.
      [scriptblock]::Create(' Execute-Payload ')
    )

  }

}

# Now invoke the function defined in the module.
Invoke-Something
```

The above outputs `Inside Execute-Payload in the script's scope.`, proving that the script's function was called.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, there are 2 commonly used ways to load custom functions to your main script. I'll give you a few examples, since, I'm not sure if there is a best practice for this.

**The script being executed will always be `main.ps1` on all given examples.**

- Example 1: All functions are stored on one file

*Folder structure*

```
../path/to/script/main.ps1
../path/to/script/Functions/functions.ps1
```

*`Functions.ps1`*

```
function myCustomFunction1 {
....
}

function myCustomFunction2 {
....
}

function myCustomFunction3 {
....
}
```

*`main.ps1`*

On the first lines of code you could add something like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Option 1: Using Import-Module.
try
{
    Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\Functions\functions.ps1"
}
catch
{
    "Failed to load dependency Functions.`nError: $_"
}

# Option 2: Dot Sourcing
try
{
    . "$PSScriptRoot\Functions\functions.ps1"
}
catch
{
    "Failed to load dependency Functions.`nError: $_"
}
```

**Note: both options will load ALL functions.**

- Example 2: Many functions stored on different files. This is used when you have lots of complex and/or lengthy functions.

*Folder structure*

```
../path/to/script/main.ps1
../path/to/script/Functions/myCustomFunction1.ps1
../path/to/script/Functions/myCustomFunction2.ps1
../path/to/script/Functions/myCustomFunction3.ps1
```

*`myCustomFunction1.ps1`*

```
function myCustomFunction1 {
....
}
```

*`myCustomFunction2.ps1`*

```
function myCustomFunction2 {
....
}
```

*`myCustomFunction3.ps1`*

```
function myCustomFunction3 {
....
}
```

*`main.ps1`*

On the first lines of code you could add something like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Option 1: Using Import-Module.
try
{
    Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\Functions\*.ps1" | Import-Module
}
catch
{
    "Failed to load dependency Functions.`nError: $_"
}

# Option 2: Dot Sourcing
try
{
    Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\Functions\*.ps1" | ForEach-Object {
        . $_.FullName
    }
}
catch
{
    "Failed to load dependency Functions.`nError: $_"
}
```